# Update and append new properties on exising resource on AWS using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm very new to Terraform and excited to use it.

I've created the `security group A` by Terraform and I want to attach the `security group A` into the `existing security group B`. I was trying to figure it out that it looks like object assign and spread operator in javascript.

I imagined like below,

```
data "aws_security_group" "A" {
  id = "<id>"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "A" {
  ...data.aws_security_group.A,
  ingress = [ ...data.aws_security_group.A.ingress]
}
```

and this is what I thought so far,

```
resource "aws_security_group" "A" {
  vpc_id = var.a_vpc_id

  ingress = [module.eks.aws_security_group.cluster] // I only want to add this ingress into the existing ingress at security group A
  lifecycle = {
    ignore_changes = [
      ingress // ignore existing ingress
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any syntax or tweak to accomplish what I want? Any reference and keyword will make me happy.

---

(Updated) almost real code.

```
variable "internal_vpc_id" {
  default = "vpc-12345678"
}

module "eks" {
 ....
}

resource "aws_security_group" "internal" {
  vpc_id = var.internal_vpc_id
  
  ingress = [
               module.eks.aws_security_group.cluster,
               module.eks.aws_security_group.workers, 
               module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.cluster_egress_internet,
            module.eks.aws_security_group_rule.cluster_https_worker_ingress
            ]
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      ingress
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide actual, reproducable code, as its not clear what `...data.aws_security_group.A,`  or `ingress = [ ...data.aws_security_group.A.ingress]`, and others mean.

Comment: @Marcin updated and it is the current code which I'm trying and is not really different from the examples.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to attach the security group A into the existing security group B

You can't directly modify SG B in terraform (TF) if its not managed by AWS using `aws_security_group`. To do that you would have to [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) B into TF. This would allow you to modify it.

To avoid the import procedure, you can use [aws_security_group_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule). This will only create a rule that want, and will attach it to an existing SG B, even if it is not managed by TF.

Therefore, using `aws_security_group_rule` you could do (pseudo code):

```
data "aws_security_group" "B" {
  id = "SG-B-id"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ruleB" {
  type                       = "ingress"
  from_port                  = 0
  to_port                    = 65535
  protocol                   = "tcp"
  source_security_group_id   = aws_security_group.A.id
  security_group_id          = data.aws_security_group.B.id
}
```

Comment: Thanks. can I access `data "aws_security_group" "B" {
  id = "SG-B-id"
}` without import? I'm pretty confused of the usage of `import`

Comment: @sunsets yes. `data` only gets information about existing resource. `import` will allow you to fully manage a resource that you are going to import.

Comment: I'm thinking that I have to take both way to migrate and use all resources from existing resources.